# My custom snackbar is not fitting my whole width sreen size

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set an customSnackBar in my activity, and it's all good less the fact that it's not covering all my screen. What could be my issue here?

This is my snackBar configuration:

```
private fun configureSnackbarWarning() {
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        val customSnackView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movements_snackbar, null)

        val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
        snackbarLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        snackbarLayout.minimumWidth = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

        // Add the custom view to the Snackbar's layout
        snackbarLayout.addView(customSnackView)
        snackbar.show()
    }
```

This is my snackbar xml (layout_movements_snackbar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/default_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_warning_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/snackbar_movements_bg_warning"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_no_movement_warning"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pagination_warning"
        android:textColor="@color/snackbar_text_warning"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I already tried to set the snackBar padding and margins to 0 and still no good results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to this

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Because you are doing this :

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

And add this

```
val customSnackView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movements_snackbar, null)
customSnackView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

### Edit

This is because you are using Material Components and they've added margin by default. So to override this, you should create a style as follows :

```
    <style name="CustomSnackBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

And then if you want a `Snackbar` to fit width then add it in your `AppTheme` of your app but note **this will affect all the Snackbars**.

```
    <style name="Base.Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
        <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/CustomSnackBar</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that didn't solve my issue.  I also already verified that my binding.root has no padding or any margin on it.

Comment: Thank you, the last suggestion solved my issue :)